# procces hidden field true ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a hidden field in form i want to proces with ajax but it doesn't work

```
formname = idke
hiddenfieldname = id

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.timeline_shout_buttons').click(function () {
        $('#nodig').dialog({
            width: 625,
            height: 'auto',
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "delete.php?id=document.getElementById(#id).value",
                        data: $("idke").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data); // show response from the php script.
                        }
                    });
                    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please update your question to tell us what you expect to happen, what happens now, and what you have done to try to fix the problem. Please consider examining the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for information that will help you to ask questions that receive good answers.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is here

```
data: $("idke").serialize()
```

You should give an `id` to the form and change the data argument like this (assuming the new `id` will also be `idke`)... notice the `#`

```
data: $("#idke").serialize()
```

[Also, see James' answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16591462/244537)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing this exact string as your url:

```
"delete.php?id=document.getElementById(#id).value"
```

What you intended to do is get the value from the element.  However, since you put it inside the `""`, it is simply a string and will not be evaluated.  You need to do something like this:

```
"delete.php?id=" + document.getElementById("id").value;
```

Notice now that the `document.getElementById` code is no longer inside the string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append your id to the POST data body like this:

```
url: "delete.php",
data: $("#idke").serialize() + "&id=" + $('#id').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
url: "delete.php?id=document.getElementById(#id).value",
```

Based on this and the php tag in your post, I assume you are coming from a background in PHP. One of the niceties of PHP is variable interpolation - replacing "My name is $name" to include whatever the value of the $name variable is.

However, javascript does not do this by default. Try replacing this particular line with something like:

```
url: "delete.php?id=" + document.getElementById("id").value,
```

Vyx.ca's answer is also correct regarding the missing # in the data line as well.

Comment: i have the correct id in this

Comment: Edited to fix my own quotation issue and remove the incorrect # sign.

Answer (score 1):

The selector "idke" in $("idke") is not a valid css selector.

Also the `document.getElementById(#id).value` will not parse if you keep it within the string `url: "delete.php?id=document.getElementById(#id).value"`. Perhaps you meant `url: "delete.php?id="+ document.getElementById("id").value`?

Comment: i have the correct id in this, var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); so i have the id but it wont procces it $.ajax({
     
             type: "GET",
           url: "delete.php"+(id),
            data: "(id)",
            success: function(data)